# Synchronizing clock over a network with maximum accuracy

Tags: network-programming, conceptual

Let's say we've got a server with ticking clock (just an integer variable that holds a number of milliseconds from epoch and being updated every time when the system time is changed).

Each client should be able to synchronize its own clock (not the system clock! just an abstract timer, an integer value that's increasing with time) with server's.

For example the client can send a "sync" request and the server will respond with its current clock value.

The problem is that we can't know exactly how much time will be taken by the sending and receiving the data. We know the time that was passed from sending the request to receiving the data, we can divide this difference by 2 and add this to the value received from server, but it is not very accurate!

Is there a common concept of synchronizing clock between server and a client with minimum difference of values on both sides after performing it?

Comment: Is there a reason your not using ntp?

Comment: What's wrong with NTP?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with NTP. The question was about concept, the algorithm that is used to synchronize time between two machines and taking in account the latency. In this case I'm not talking about system clock, just an abstract timer in a program that should be synchronized between two instances over a network.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using NTP (Network Time Protocol) for this, it is just the way to synchronize clocks in an entire network.

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

Almost every operating system out there (I manage Linux, Solaris, BSD and Windows) have clients and servers for NTP. The protocol has build in capabilities to take care of network latency.

Comment: I need to understand the consept behind such protocols. I don't need to synchronize the system clock. Just an abstract timer in the application.

Comment: NTP solves that kind of problem and uses many really good ideas. You can always get the detailed description in the RFC of NTP:

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5905.txt